# What exactly does gradlew app:dependencies do?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

An app of mine was crashing on Android 4.4.4 giving the following runtime exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

My gradle file showed the following lint error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version...

I read something on stack that made be type this into the terminal:

> gradlew app:dependencies

It listed all my library/project dependencies. It also has this in some areas:

```
     +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0 -> 25.1.0
```

The above looks like it's updating the libraries I've added to the latest support library versions.

Anyway, after using the above command and rebuilding the project, the app started to work even though I still see the lint error regarding different support library versions.

**What exactly does gradlew app:dependencies do? And did it fix the error I was getting?**

Answer (score 0):

> dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project
>   'projectReports'.

So it's quite clear what it does. So why it fixed problem? I don't think it was fixed because of `app:dependencies` was executed, mostly I think it was fixed due fact that you've rebuilt project. Sometimes, probably due bug in build system (or more often because of instant run "feature"), you can end up with inconsistent apk file.

Comment: I've rebuilt this several times before as well, and it ran fine on >5.0 devices. The bug on 4.4 was fixed after I did that. I know it makes no sense, and that is why I posted this here, hoping for some clarification.